# WordPress numbering need to fix

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

[see image ][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERM84.jpg
 how can i fix this problem.in woocommerce product discription number lists numbers goes to bottom line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your markup, but you can try adding `vertical-align: top;` to your `li`